# ¿Unbundle de un solo archivo usando python?

Tags: python

Hola buenas me preguntaron en un examen sobre hacer "unbundle" de un archivo tipo asi:

```
archivo1 Hola que tal?
archivo1 esto es una linea del archivo1
archivo2.py Sevilla tiene un color especial
archivo2.py if var in entry:
archivo3.txt Unbundle en varios archivos
```

Me pedía separar cada línea en un archivo, cuyo nombre es la primera palabra, en este caso `archivo1`, `archivo2.py` o `archivo3.txt`, es decir coge la linea lee hasta que haya 1 espacio y ese es el nombre del archivo, seguidamente despues del espacio lee y escribe esa linea en el archivo1, en este caso, luego siguiente, cambia de linea y es `archivo2.py` crea ese archivo, y lee despues del espacio y escribe en el archivo la linea.

Estoy empezando el fp superior de DAW y la verdad no consigo ponerme al dia, recordad que no hemos dado nada dificil, ni complicado, supongo que es hacer un `open('archivo','r')`, `.write()`, cosas asi, pero me trabo, gracias.

Comment: ¿Habeis dado "slices"? (o sea, lo de extraer parte de una cadena con `variable[inicio:fin]`). ¿Habeis dado diccionarios y listas?

Comment: Si, dimos diccionarios, listas, y eso de slices pero no dijeron ese nombre, solo como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Sin darte la solución explícitamente, pues entiendo que al ser un trabajo de clase la solución tienes que crearla tú, te doy algunas ideas de cómo atacarlo, con las herramientas que de momento sabes manejar, que supongo que son las siguientes:

- Conoces cómo iterar por listas mediante un bucle `for`.
- Conoces algunos métodos para operar sobre cadenas, como el método `.find()` para encontrar un carácter dentro de una cadena.
- Conoces cómo crear listas y añadirles elementos mediante `.append()`
- Conoces los diccionarios y cómo añadirles elementos o iterar sobre ellos.

Con estas herramientas, el *pseudocódigo* que deberías ser capaz de convertir a Python sería el siguiente:

```
1. Abrir fichero "bundle" y leerlo con `fichero.readlines()`. 
   El resultado es una lista cuyos elementos son las líneas del archivo.
2. Crear un diccionario vacío. 
   La misión de ese diccionario será tener como claves los nombres de archivos,
   y como valores una lista con las líneas que deberían ir a ese fichero.
3. Iterar sobre la lista leída en el punto 1.
   3.1 Para cada elemento, aplicarle `.find(" ")` para localizar la aparición 
       del primer espacio. Guardar el resultado en una variable llamada espacio.
   3.2 Tomar elemento[:espacio] y eso será un nombre de archivo
   3.3 Tomar elemento[espacio+1:] y eso será una línea que ha de ir en ese archivo
   3.4 Si el nombre no estaba en el diccionario creado en 2
          hacer diccionario[nombre] = []
       y si no
          hacer diccionario[nombre].append(resto_linea)

Al salir del bucle el diccionario tendrá la información deseada, sus claves
serán los nombres de ficheros y sus valores las líneas de cada uno.

4. Iterar por el diccionario.
   4.1 Para cada elemento, usar la clave como nombre de archivo y crearlo
       con open(nombre, "w")
   4.2 Para cada elemento, el valor de esa entrada es una lista. Iterar por la lista
       4.2.1 Cada elemento de la lista escribirlo en el archivo
   4.3 Cerrar archivo
```

También puedes evitar la construcción del diccionario si, a medida que procesas las líneas en el bucle 3, llevas en una variable cuál ha sido el último nombre de fichero visto. Cuando aparece uno nuevo, cierras el fichero anterior y abres uno nuevo. Mientras sea el mismo vas volcando líneas en él. Aunque este enfoque te evita el diccionario, es más difícil de implentar correctamente, pues tiene una lógica más compleja.

Con estas ideas ya tienes más que suficiente para ponerte a implementar. Si durante la implementación encuentras errores puedes preguntara de nuevo (no lo hagas como respuesta a esta misma pregunta, sino editando tu pregunta original o creando una nueva) pero no olvides incluir el código de lo que llevas hecho.

## Actualización

Otra forma más simple, pero más ineficiente sería en cada línea de entrada abrir un archivo de salida para volcar la línea correspondiente. Esto obliga a cerrar de nuevo el archivo de salida tras cada línea, pues no sabemos si la línea siguiente irá al mismo archivo o a otro. Por eso también es necesario abrir los archivos de salida en modo "append" para que añada a lo que había.

Quedaría así:

```
entrada = open("entrada.txt")
for linea in entrada:
   palabras = linea.split(" ")
   salida = open(palabras[0], "a")  # Modo append
   salida.write(" ".join(palabras[1:]))  # Volcar el resto de la linea
   salida.close()
entrada.close()
```

Fijate que lo que vuelco al fichero de salida no es `palabras[1:]` sin más, pues eso sería una lista, sino que uso `" ".join()` para convertir esa lista de nuevo en una cadena, intercalando espacios entre sus palabras (los que habían desaparecido debido al `.split()`.

Comment: gracias pero no me es muy util, ya que he visto hacerlo sin todo eso que dices, y por lo visto no hay que hacer tantas cosas, además al no poner el script se me hace dificil seguirte, perdona la demora.

Comment: Otra posible forma que se me ocurre, que quizás es la que has visto, puede ser iterar en cada línea, tomar su primera palabra, abrir un fichero con ese nombre en modo "append" y guardar en él el resto de la línea, y volver a cerrarlo. Basta repetir esto para todas las líneas. Tanto abrir y cerrar ficheros es más ineficiente, pero el resultado sería el mismo. No se me ocurre forma más simple, de todas formas. Si das con ella puedes publicar tu respuesta.

Comment: esque como lo he visto no usaban listas, explico, lo digo cómo lo vi, el script leia el archivo bundle, cogia la primera palabra antes del espacio, con un split, escribia un archivo con ese nombre (NombreSplit[0]) y luego le añadía lo que estuviese a partir del 1 (linea[1:]), todo esto en un bucle, y al acabar porque no hay mas lineas cierra el archivo escrito y luego el leido. nose si puedes escribirme el script que funcione, ya es por tenerlo claro y cabezonería mia, además de tenerlo ya en mis manos.

Comment: @Weketee Editada la respuesta para darte la solución. A estas alturas supongo que ya no importa si te hago yo la tarea :-)

Comment: Exacto, sale bien ahora, yo lo que hacía era esto: a=open('bundle','r')
linea=a.readline()
lista=linea.split(" ")
while linea:
 linea=a.readline()
 b = open(lista[0], 'w')
 for var in lista[1:]:
  b.write(var)
 b.close()
a.close() Nosé por qué pero no salta de línea, se queda en la primera y me salta con la misma primera palabra todo el rato, alguna idea de por qué?

Comment: Lo que tú hacías tenía dos cosas mal. Al abrir el fichero en modo `"w"`, en cada iteración borraba lo que hubiera antes, por lo que sólo queda al final la última línea. Y lo de la `lista[1:]` que ya explico en la respuesta te guarda una lista de cadenas en vez de una cadena.

Comment: Entiendo, y lo de que solo me imprimía la primera palabra una y otra vez? Me explico leia el archivo y split, y luego pone while linea: y después que me lea línea seguido de un print(split[0]) para que me imprima lo splitteado en la posicion 0, pero me imprimía el primero (osea el 0) tantas veces como número de líneas, no sé si me he explicado bien.

Comment: No te entiendo muy bien, no... y es que los comentarios no son buen sitio para poner código. ¿Por qué no creas una nueva pregunta, pones el código que has intentado y lo que te salía y planteas la duda? Así me podré explicar mejor yo también en otra respuesta.

Comment: Creo una nueva pues.